# Do users of a third party app accessing our API's have to log in with us even if they've already authenticated with their their system?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a third party company developing a mobile app and they want to call our API's. Our API is protected with Identity Server 4 which uses OpenID Connect and OAuth2. In order to access our API's would their app have to pop open a mobile browser so the user can log into our system? What if users already authenticated with the third party's identity provider? Seems like that would create a negative user experience to authenticate two different times while using the app.

My understanding is we would add their app as a client in Identity Server using the authorization code grant. Would we add their identity provider as an identity provider that our Identity Server can call?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've researched myself into a hole.

Comment: If "their" system supports token validation, then you could accept their OAuth token, validate it and proceed as normal. You have left out the important details ...

Answer (score 0):

> would their app have to pop open a mobile browser so the user can log into our system?

You are pretty much right on your assumptions that their app would have to somehow initiate oidc flow to allow the users of the mobile app to authenticate with the authority of your API (identity provider).

> Seems like that would create a negative user experience to authenticate two different times while using the app.

It seems that this is what's holding you back. Firstly, that mobile app's identity provider is separate from your API's authority and it is important to understand that the "user" authenticated with the other identity provider means close to nothing to your API because the token has been issued by a different authority and it's not even a "user" from your user base.

> My understanding is we would add their app as a client in Identity Server using the authorization code grant.

Yes, but check also Authorization Code grant with PKCE which adds extra security measures.

> Would we add their identity provider as an identity provider that our Identity Server can call?

Yes, you will need to do that, but this is just a start of the things you would need to do to achieve what you are looking for. Because you already have Identity Server 4 in place, I assume your systems already have an established user base, therefore if you just redirect to the external identity provider, once a user authenticates there and the token is issued back - that kinda means nothing because you don't have any kind of mapping from the user of the third party system to the user of your system.

There is pretty much nothing out of the box in Identity Server 4 that will help you with this, but one way to tackle this is to implement some sort of account linking mechanism, where the users would first have to "link" their account in your system with the account in the third party system. With account linked, you would have means to issue claims related to your system.

Comment: Indeed, it's the re-authenticating we're trying to prevent. We don't want their users to have to re-log in with a browser to access our API's.

Comment: You should just be able to pass the users access token as a bearer token

Comment: Our 3rd party client would send a bearer token when calling our API's, but the question is what flow should they use to obtain that token that minimizes user interaction.

Comment: If the token needs to identify a user in your system through your idp (which I assumed it does) - then you can use authorization code with pkce for the mobile app.

Comment: @Lenny Sockman. 3rd party... sorry, didn't see that.  In that case, this is what the client credentials grant type is used for.  OIr you could just create a user for that client, and get a bearer token using the resource owner password grant type.  All you have to do is hit the token endpoint and pass the grant type and whatever else you need for that grant type to get a bearer token.  This answer says there is nothing out of the box to do this, but there clearly is.  There are several out of the box options.

Answer (score -1):

Identity Server 4 absolutly has out of the box solutions for this.  If they didn't, what would be the point calling themselve a OAuth 2.0 framework?

You do not need to initiated a oidc flow like stated. What does that even mean anyway? oidc is connection protocol, not a flow.  Flows include hybrid, implicit, clientcredential, etc.

You could obtain an access token for your 3rd party app a number of ways all use the token endpoint built into identity server 4 specifically for creating access tokens The most common is using the ClientCredential flow, where you gain a bearer token by hitting the identity server 4 token endpoint passing the client_credentials grant type with the ClientId of the client they want to access, a shared secret supplied by you, and the api scope they are attempting to access.

Another option is you could create a user for this client on Identity Server 4, then gain an access token using the ResourceOwnerPassword flow by hitting the token endpoint passing the password grant type, clientId, username, and password, again along with the api scope they want to access.

For information on how to do all of the above check out his link.  It will help you on your way.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html